# JNA, Converting C function pointers to JNA

Tags: jna

I have C function with a function pointer call back as below

```
lm_cont* lm_start(lm_cont *context,  int (*lm_rep)(lm_cont))
{
  ....
  .....
}
```

I am trying to create a JNA conversion

1. Creating an interface for callback as below

   ```
   public interface lmCallback {
       public int lm_rep(lm_cont test);
   }
   ```
2. And then in main method, loading the dll and calling the native function.
   Note: lm_cont is a structure which i have created as a Java class.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       JavaInterface jInterface = (JavaInterface)Native.loadLibrary("C:\\EclipseWorkspace\\zzzz.dll", 
           JavaInterface.class);


       lm_cont.ByReference var= new lm_cont.ByReference(); 
       var.id = "45rf67";
       var = (lm_cont.ByReference) jInterface.lm_start(var, new lmCallback() {

           public int lm_rep(dm_cont test) {               
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return 0;
           }

       } );
   ```

But the compiler gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type LoadLibrary$1 at parameter 1 of function lm_start
    at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:558)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:258)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:218)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.dm_start(Unknown Source)
```

What is wrong in my Java declarations?. Any help is very much appreciated. 
And also any sample JNA code for the C function that i have pasted above will be very helpful.

Comment: Show your `lm_start` mapping.